# django: Cannot assign "1": "TitleVideoModel.video_id" must be a "VideosModel" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an API for adding items in my database table. My current code is https://github.com/scaltro/youtubeapp/blob/master/myupload/views.py .

The problem is when i try to post data in my api http://142.93.130.167:1080/api/titles I get this error :

> Cannot assign "1": "TitleVideoModel.video_id" must be a "VideosModel" instance

What is wrong? How I can fix this error?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, have made a `ForeignKey` `video_id`? Don't do that! A foreign key refers to the object itself, so it should be `video = ForeignKey(Video)`, then Django will make automatically an extra field named `video_id` for the `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the object of `VideosModel` so Django could map it via relation. So in `TitlesView` you could do something like this:

```
try:
   video = VideosModel.objects.get(id=video_id)

    t = TitleVideoModel(
        title=title,
        video=video,
        publicato=publicato,
        youtube_url=youtube_url,
        author=author,
        created_at=created_at,
        updated=updated_at,
    )
except VideosModel.DoesNotExist:
    # Handle the case when video by id is not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to assign an integer (which could or be the ID of a `VideosModel`, or it might just be a random integer) into a foreignkey field.

Looking at your code, there're many non-djangoisms I'd fix:

- Model names should be in singular (unless they refer to a group of things, in which case I'd just tack on `Group` anyway), that is `VideosModel` should be `VideoModel`.
- Model names should not contain the word `Model`; it's obvious they're Models. (Consider Django's built-in `User`. It isn't `UserModel`). So, to add to the above: make `VideosModel` just `Video`.
- `ForeignKey` fields should not end with `_id`. They're not ID fields *an sich*, even if behind the scenes they're backed by ID fields, which happen to be called `FIELDNAME_id` – that is, your model will have a physical database field called `video_id_id`. 
  So, `TitleVideoModel.video_id` should just be `video`.
  In fact, renaming this field will make your API work, but only by accident. You can assign ID values to the field backing the foreign key in Django, which is good to know when you only have the ID and don't want to pull up the actual object just to assign it.

Then there are non-DRFisms. You should really use a `rest_framework.viewsets.ModelViewSet` for what is now `TitlesList`/`TitleDetail`/`TitlesView`, and you'd get all of the code you've now hand-rolled for validating those serializers and setting defaults for values, etc. out of the box.

I suggest reading the [DRF tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#refactoring-to-use-viewsets) on viewsets.

Answer (score 0):

`video_id` needs to be an instance of `VideosModel` so replace:

```
video_id = video_id
```

by:

```
video_id = VideosModel.objects.get(pk=video_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Django `ForeignKey` names

The trouble is actually more located in the `models.py` than in the `views.py`. A common mistake Django developers make is writing something like:

> ```
> class TitleVideoModel(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     video_id = models.ForeignKey(VideosModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
> ```

Here you define a `ForeignKey` that refers to a `VideosModel` instance. Now in the database of course this will be stored as an column that refers to the primary key value of the `VideosModel` table), but at the Django level, this is actually a (lazy) reference to a `VideosModel` object. So the name should be `video` instead of `videos`:

```
class TitleVideoModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    video = models.ForeignKey(VideosModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Why is that important? Because for a `ForeignKey`, Django makes *two* attributes: the `video`, and the `video_id` (in the old version it would be `video_id_id`, but that is a a rather *ugly* name). The `video` lazily refers to the `VideosModel` instance, and its twin `video_id` stores the primary key. In fact the `video` attribute is a bit "virtual", since in the database, only the `video_id` exists.

So you can set the primary key, without first making a fetch for the object, by simply writing:

```
some_titlevideomodel.video_id = 123
some_titlevideomodel.save()
```

and then you can directly update the reference. Since Django adds foreign key constraints, this will also error if `123` is not a valid primary key value. The same happens with filtering, updating, creating, etc. When writing `video_id`, it will accept a primary key value (by default a primary key is an integer), and thus use that one.

I suggest you rename the relation, and construct a migration, since this more Django-ish.

## Alternative: use `video_id_id`

If you do not want to rename the `ForeignKey`, you can rewrite it to:

```
t = TitleVideoModel(
    title=title,
    video_id_id=video_id,
    publicato=publicato,
    youtube_url=youtube_url,
    author=author,
    created_at=created_at,
    updated=updated_at
)
```

But this will in the end typically only result in more confusion. Although it requires some work to fix the situation now, I think in the end, it is likely that your effort will be worth it.

> **Note**: Django style also specifies that models should have *singular* names, and typically do *not* end with `Model`, so `TitleVideo` instead of `TitleVideoModel`, and `Video` instead of `VideosModel`.